# How do I select a model within Siemens S7-1200 PLC?

Tags: plc, siemens

I want to buy and use Siemens S7-1200 PLC.

But there are so many models inside the 1200 PLC family that is confusing for a beginner.

See the list:
[image]

I am just using a sensor which works on both AC/DC.

How do I make my selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand the controller and click on a part number it will give you a detailed description of what the plc has (I/O, work memory, etc.)

[image]

If it is true all you are using is a sensor then you may want to go with a less expensive CPU 1211C or something similar.  But you should look at the description and see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

When choosing a Siemens S7-1200 PLC for your AC/DC sensor, consider factors such as I/O configuration, power supply, memory, and communication capabilities. The CPU 1214C AC/DC/Relay is a good choice with 14 digital inputs, 10 digital outputs, and 2 analog inputs. It can be powered by AC or DC, enough memory for most applications, and communication capabilities. Other factors to consider include price, ease of use, and Siemens' support. The CPU 1214C AC/DC/Relay is a good choice for its versatility and compatibility with AC or DC power supplies.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541